# How to process pair array data

Tags: go

I have json data like:

```
`[{"fea1":12345},{"fea2":23456}]`
```

I want to unmarshal them into Go structs.

Now I defined a struct like `[]map[string]int`.

It works, but I think this is not the best way which processing pair data with map structure.

Processing large data set also cost much resource if using map structure.

Is there a more graceful way to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have predefined set of fields, you may use struct like this:

```
type Fea struct {
    Fea1 int `json:"fea1,omitempty"`
    Fea2 int `json:"fea2,omitempty"`
}

type Feas []Fea

var feas Feas
```

Then `Unmarshal` to `feas`. This way present fields would be filled, others would be empty.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunately, keys are arbitrary strings. I can't list them all.

Comment: @cnby What's a best structure you want to see? For example, you may convert to `[]struct{name string, value int}`.